Meaning of ということ / っていうこと in this context
''これは認めたってことでいいですか？''
Need some help understanding the concept of ''ということ''.
I've always been vaguely confused by it and would like an explanation to what it means here if possible. Tried searching around for any good explanations but there hasn't been any direct answers that I could find.

“ということでいい” is a further idiom built upon “ということだ” but one can see it as something like “It's safe to say that ...” or “We can safely say that.” It's indeed often interrogative so the sentence means “So it's safe to say you acknowledge it?”
“ということだ” itself is indeed a bit tricky but it's roughtly similar to “meaning that ...” or “in other words” or “implying that”. Perhaps some examples work better:

“もう怒ってないってこと?” -> “You mean you're no longer angry?”
“つまり、高橋さんには興味がないということです。” -> “In short, what I mean to say is that I have no interest in you.”
“二人は兄弟だということですか？” -> “Do you mean to tell me that you two are siblings?”

Is it also often started with “それは” or “それって”

I see... yeah it makes sense

これは認めたってことでいいですか？-Does this mean you approve of this?
it doesn't mean much.
これは〜ってことでいいですか？"Does this mean ~?"
This is a syntax.
I think ということ is used to make a verb into nouns, but in this sentence, even if it is a noun that goes inside, it is still used.
